# JavaScript: Override get and set but keep native functionality

Tags: javascript, prototype, getter, setter

For testing: I need to override the native access to properties of HTMLElement in JavaScript, but keep the native functionality.

The following code overrides the `offsetWidth` property of `HTMLElement` but I can't figure out how to log the result of the native getter.

```
// How can I call this from within the getter?

var nativeOffsetWidth = HTMLElement.prototype.offsetWidth;

// Overrides the native access

Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, 'offsetWidth', {
    
    get: () => {

        // This part does not work! I need to access the native property here.

        var value = nativeOffsetWidth.call(this);

        console.log(value);
        return value;
        
    }
    
});
```

I would also like to modify the result once i can get the correct `value`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the original value of a property using [Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor)

Use it like this:

```
const nativeOffsetWidth = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(
    HTMLElement.prototype,
    'offsetWidth'
).get;
nativeOffsetWidth.call(document.body /* example html element */);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, I could not get the code provided to produce a result. I will look into getOwnPropertyDescriptor and see if I can get it to work with some modifications.

Comment: I tested my code in both Chrome and Firefox, not sure why it wouldn't work sometimes

Comment: I works great with document.body, but I can't get it to work with the "this" keyword from within the getter, e.g. nativeOffsetWidth.call(this).

Comment: Ah I see your problem. The `this` keyword does not work like normal in arrow functions. Use a normal function and it should work as expected

Comment: @mousetail i check and happens too with properties, here an example: https://pastebin.com/00kUEBbD don't understand at all why don't set with **this**

Comment: @AlumnoCabreado I'm not sure what you mean, if you have a separate question ask it separately rather than cluttering the comments here

Comment: See the lines 5 and 6 of https://pastebin.com/00kUEBbD The value isn't stored using **this.property**

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect that code to do. You are making `offsetWidth` a closure variable rather than an object variable, which probably is not what you want. Again, please ask a new question if you have a separate issue.

Comment: Hi again, im not asking what does that script otherwise only asking why ``this.offsetWidth = offsetW;`` don't store the property, i think thats very small question for open a new question, I do not force you to answer, you can ignore me if you want.